# How to combine another Laravel validation rule with 'required_without_all'

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5.3

I am working with Laravel 5.3.

I am trying to implement the ['required_without_all'](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-required-without-all) validation rule. I have it working as expected, however I want to add an additional rule (ie a minimum value rule). But I want this additional validation rule to run **only** if there is a value present in the field.

So to summarise, I have several fields and want the following validation:

- At least one field out of them should be filled in (achieved this
  using the 'required_without_rule').
- For fields that are filled in, I
  want a minimum value rule.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `'my_field' => 'required_without_all:field,another_field | min:40'` Doesn't work?

Comment: @GerardReches Nope, it then ends up validating all the fields (incl. empty ones) and not just the one that is filled in.

Comment: Try with `'my_field' => 'required_without_all:field,another_field | sometimes | min:40'`

Comment: @GerardReches this works! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First validation rule: `required_without_all:foo,bar,...`

> The field under validation must be present and not empty only when all of the other specified fields are not present.

Second validation rule: `sometimes`

> In some situations, you may wish to run validation checks against a field only if that field is present in the input array. To quickly accomplish this, add the sometimes rule to your rule list

Third validation rule: `min:value`

> The field under validation must have a minimum value. Strings, numerics, and files are evaluated in the same fashion as the size rule.

---

So the validation rules for your fields should look like:

```
'my_field' => 'required_without_all:field,another_field | sometimes | min:40'
```